# React blank page after running npm run build because of react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here is my code for the index.js page:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom"
import './css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './css/style.css';

// Pages
import Library from './pages/Library.js'
import Register from './pages/Register.js'

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Library}/>
        <Route exact path="/library" component={Library}/>
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

When I run `npm start` I get the application as desired. `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3000/library` render the Library component, while `localhost:3000/register` renders the Register component.

When I run `npm run build` I get the build folder but when I enter the index.html page, it is blank.

This problem was introduced after I implemented the router. Previously the result of both `npm start` and `npm run build` were the same.

Comment: you need to serve your index.html from a server

Comment: ^ I don't know what that means.

Comment: You should read [deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)

Comment: Similar:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/62103419/2873538

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6275) to the same issue you are facing on the official create-react-app github issues

It is marked as closed there, you can also read that for more info.

You should serve the build folder for example like

```
npx serve -s build
```