# Unable to deploy React project using XAMPP

Tags: reactjs, deployment, xampp

How can I build my project so I can put it wherever I want? For example, I would love to see it on, if it's possible, **XAMPP**?

Whenever I build my react app, **index.html** is empty.

Here is the whole project on GitHub: https://github.com/slabys/reacty.git

Whenever I use `npm run build`, my folder **build** is created with all the content:

[image: Build structure]
[image: Full app structure]

**index.html** from build: https://pastebin.com/WSyAvrwu

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "my_react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@stardust-ui/docs-components": "^0.40.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "del": "^5.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-favicon": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-copy": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-data": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-twig": "^1.2.0",
    "prettier": "^1.4.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-sidebar": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^5.6.4",
    "@semantic-ui-react/craco-less": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "semantic-ui-less": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "author": "slabys",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "react"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: You can deploy react app using xampp or any other web sever. Check [deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53816284/2873538)

Comment: Yeah index.html is not totally empty, but it still did not contain all the things I did... basically its only white page.
So if I'm gonna take "build" folder and I'm gonna move it into XAMPP htdocs all I'am gonna see is white page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

All works fine. Just when I have this projects `build` in **XAMPP htdocs**, I put in into a folder. So after moving files from folder **directly under** localhost EVERYTHING started to work.

Comment: this needs to be explain in more detail